# onDraw of custom view not being called

Tags: android

I have a custom view extending ImageView.  onDraw() is never called.

Nothing complicated:

```
public class NVGlobeView extends ImageView{
```

I have all 3 constructors:

```
 public NVGlobeView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public NVGlobeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public NVGlobeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
```

I've overidden onMeasure and forced a fixed size to ensure that the view does not have a zero dimension.  I know that my view is added to the layout since onMeasure() is called and I can step through it to verify the size is set correctly.  I've also validated it with the heirarchy viewer on an AVD.

```
 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        //setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

        DisplayMetrics dm = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        setMeasuredDimension(dm.widthPixels-50,dm.heightPixels-100);
}
```

Finally, the onDraw()

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

}
```

I put a breakpoint on the super call and it's never reached.

Here's the associated activity code.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.nvglobeview);

    NVGlobeView globeView = (NVGlobeView)findViewById(R.id.globeView);
    globeView.invalidate();
```

Any ideas what I've missed?

Comment: create a new line just before calling `invalidate()` and in this line call `globeView.getWidth()`, set a breakpoint and check what is returned. `DisplayMetrics` may contain different values depending on the settings in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

A guess, maybe the measurement you return is such that the view takes no visible space.

Comment: From my OP - `I've overidden onMeasure and forced a fixed size to ensure that the view does not have a zero dimension. I know that my view is added to the layout since onMeasure() is called and I can step through it to verify the size is set correctly. I've also validated it with the heirarchy viewer on an AVD.`

Comment: It's still worth trying. You can also set a background color for your view and check if you see it on screen.

Comment: One more guess, maybe the compiler is smart enough to remove your onDraw as it does nothing